# onLoad clashing with onerror function

Tags: html

Creating the simple status checker, however when the image fails to load and the src is changed to the offline symbol the onLoad function is triggered and changes the image to the online one even if the website is offline.

I know I can solve this by hosting the online symbol on the website i am testing, but i want to be able to test websites that i don't own or like blogger where the image is not hosted on your domain.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>
            eTree Status
        </title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="margin: 20px; background-color: #EEE; width: 400px; padding: 10px;">
            <img style="height:20px;" src="http://s.etree.biz/1AKeMjI" alt="status" onLoad="this.src='http://s.etree.biz/1E94ZDh'" onerror="this.src='http://s.etree.biz/1zQwvPm'" />
             blog.etree.biz
             <br/>
            <img style="height:20px;" src="http://s.etree.biz/1G7agdE" alt="status" onLoad="this.src='http://s.etree.biz/1E94ZDh'" onerror="this.src='http://s.etree.biz/1zQwvPm'" />
             www.etree.biz
             <br />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, the problem in your code is that `onload` will fire after you assign success/error image in `onerror`, so you can just disable it.

To do this, simply clear the `onload` handler inside `onerror` and `onload` handler, for example:

```
<img src="http://example.org/image.png"
     onload="this.onload=null; this.src='success.png'"
     onerror="this.onload=null; this.src='error.png'">
```

**EDIT**: If you need to display some actual spinner while loading remote image, you can use **one `img` to show *spinner* & *success/error* images** and **another `img` to actually *retrieve the remote img*** (that fires `onload` and `onerror`.

Here's an example:

```
<!-- unexisting site or broken IMG -->
<div>
    <img id="state-1" src="http://www.xiconeditor.com/image/icons/loading.gif" />
    <img src="http://unexisting.com/"
         style="display: none"
         onload="document.getElementById('state-1').src = 'https://education.skype.com/assets/guest-speaker-signup/success-icon-255193729c9e0a50b2d36055359dd877.png';"
         onerror="document.getElementById('state-1').src = 'http://creativity-online.com/assets/images/sprites-retina/icon-error.png';" />
    Site 1
</div>

<!-- existing site with existing IMG -->
<div>
    <img id="state-2" src="http://www.xiconeditor.com/image/icons/loading.gif" />
    <img src="http://www.coffeecup.com/images/icons/applications/web-image-studio_128x128.png"
         style="display: none"
         onload="document.getElementById('state-2').src = 'https://education.skype.com/assets/guest-speaker-signup/success-icon-255193729c9e0a50b2d36055359dd877.png';"
         onerror="document.getElementById('state-2').src = 'http://creativity-online.com/assets/images/sprites-retina/icon-error.png';" />
    Site 2
</div>
```

...and here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/andunai/2s2qeuyd/

Comment: Do you know of a way to have a loading symbol, instead of showing the image we are actually loading? Or, if possible, hide the image until it has either loaded or errored?

Comment: @AustinCollins I've updated my answer, check it out ;)

Comment: Just been playing around with styling, the typical image onload and onerror works fine. Being so little code the image loads almost instantly meaning it doesn't look to bad. If you want to take a look, go to http://status.etreeblog.com/ (Password: test) and check it out. If that goes down try status.etree.biz. Thanks for the help.